# Javascript console.log command in Django is not working?

Tags: javascript, python, django, web

i am trying to print in chrome console for debugging. if i am running the same code without Django then console.log() is working fine, but while using it in Django console.log() is not printing anything. i searched the web about it and i didn't got any direct answer.

```
var inputDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".todo");
console.log(inputDiv)
```

The above code is from my Js file in my project. If i am directly executing these code in chrome console then it's working fine.I am also new to Django please help.

Comment: console.log has nothing to do with django.

Comment: @Mox every thing else is working fine except console.log() command.

Comment: a very easy way to check, just open your browser and try to locate that console.log in your javascript file.

Comment: @Mox i checked in chrome source. console.log() command is not showing there. can you please tell why ?

Comment: if u used django, did u run collectstatic?

Comment: cant believe this crap. All i had to do is clear all the cache from my chrome browser. puff..

Comment: Its better you do all the web related development work in a Private Tab of the browser. Or incognito mode. It will not cache the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Static files like JS CSS should be added like this ---

```
<script src="{% static 'djangoapp/js/app.js' %}"></script>
```

link your js file like this your console.log will work.

Project Structure should be like this--

```
djangoapp-
    template-
         djangoapp-
              index.html\
    static-
         djangoapp-
              css-
                 main.css
              js-
                 app.js
```

Comment: everything else is working so my file placement in Django is fine.

Comment: link your js file like this

<script src="{% static 'djangoapp/js/app.js' %}"/>